# How can I fetch only the numeric value from the table below. Every time the length may vary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following records in a table.

```
'JACKSONVILLE, FL'               
'CONT NET AVG-02/01 194.91'
'CONT NET AVG- 02/01  594.98'
'CONT NET AVG- 03/01 694.05'
```

The length may vary, but I require only `'194.91','594.98','694.05'`. Is there any way to fetch only this part using some form of regular expression in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is confirm that there is always value like 3 digit before decimal, then below regex can be use to get required output-

```
select SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))
from table_name
```

If your requirement is something changed than please comment.

Comment: Working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

1. First way:

```sql
select SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))
from table_name
```

2. Second Way:

```sql
select SUBSTRING(fieldName, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]%', fieldName), LEN(fieldName))
from table_name
```

Comment: Working fine, Thanks.